# Why is does the variable never decrease?

Tags: variables, python-2.7

```
def complex():
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to run this program?")

    answer = answer.lower()

    money = 5

    if "yes" in answer:
        print money
        money = money - 1
        complex()

    else:
        quit()

complex()
```

For some reason, every-time I enter "yes" into the raw_input it spits out 5. But I want it to spit out 5 then when I type yes again I want it to spit out 4, and then if I type yes again I want it to spit out 3....

I fixed this by using the Global statement:

```
money = 5
def complex():
answer = raw_input("Would you like to run this program?")
answer = answer.lower()


    if "yes" in answer:
        global money
        print money
        money = money - 1
        complex()

    else:
        quit()

complex()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your procedure is doing :

1. Get user input
2. Set variable `money` to 5
3. Validate if user input value is "yes" and if so print value if variable `money` which is 5.
4. Set variable `money` to 5 - 1 = 4
5. Run procedure `complex()`
6. Get user input
7. Set variable `money` to 5
8. Validate if user input value is "yes" and if so print value if variable `money` which is 5.
9. Set variable `money` to 5 - 1 = 4
10. Run procedure `complex()`

...
etc.

As you can see your procedure is overwriting the desired value (4) with the value of 5 with each iteration that that is why it is not working as you desire.

What you could do is make a loop to run x number of times after `money` has been set to five.

Answer (score 1):

`money` is a local variable for the `complex` function.

Every time you call `complex` function the variable is created.

Try to create the variable before the method.

Comment: What do you mean "before the method"?

Comment: I took "money = 5" from out of the function and I put it with no indentation before the function. The error I got was:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'money' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Within the "complex" function, you keep resetting the money variable to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Since you call complex(), the line
    money = 5
keeps being called.  To work around this, your recursive call should not include this setting.  Alternatively, use iteration.

Comment: Can you please give an example, I am still very new to programming and I;m not sure what you mean...

Comment: I just mean that you need to do the initial declaration, "money = 5" outside of the "loop" that is occurring since you are recursively calling "complex()".  For example, put this: if "yes" in answer:
        print money
        money = money - 1
        complex()

    else:
        quit()if "yes" in answer:
        print money
        money = money - 1
        someOtherMethodCall()
in a different method, someOtherMethodCall, and then call this method instead of calling "complex()" recursively.  This lets the recursive loop not include the declaration of "money = 5".

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to properly format code indentation, etc., in comments.

Answer (score 0):

change money = money - one to a different variable you are using it too many times and it will take money as 5

```
print dollars 
dollars = money - 1
```

Comment: I get how to do this in theory, but could you give an example with it in the code?